# Swift - Let Constant Value Disappears Stepping To Next Line

Tags: swift, swift3

I am attempting to overlay a weather radar image onto a map. I get the image and its world data file which tells me where to overlay it on the map. I have to calculate the mapRect of the image from the data associated with the image. My mapRect did not seem to be coming through correctly, so I broke out the code following my let constants of deltaX and deltaY. There is a breakpoint at deltaX so I can see what is happening. When I step over deltaX, it properly assigns the value. When I step over deltaY, deltaX's data disappears, and then deltaY's.

The function is as follows:

```
func parseWorldFileData(worldFileStringToParse: String) -> (worldFileDataStruct) {

    worldFileDataToParse = worldFileStringToParse.components(separatedBy: "\n") //componentsSeparatedByString("\n")

    for i in 0...5 {
        worldFileDataToParse[i] = String(worldFileDataToParse[i].characters.dropLast(2))
    }

    if self.worldFileDataToParse.count >= 6 {

        worldFileData.xDimension = Double(self.worldFileDataToParse[0])!
        worldFileData.rotationParam1 = Double(self.worldFileDataToParse[1])!
        worldFileData.rotationParam2 = Double(self.worldFileDataToParse[2])!
        worldFileData.yDimension = Double(self.worldFileDataToParse[3])!
        worldFileData.xCoordinate = (Double(self.worldFileDataToParse[4])! as CLLocationDegrees)
        worldFileData.yCoordinate = (Double(self.worldFileDataToParse[5])! as CLLocationDegrees)
        worldFileData.easternLongitude = (self.worldFileData.xCoordinate + ((Double(self.worldFileData.imageWidth)) * self.worldFileData.xDimension) as CLLocationDegrees)
        worldFileData.southernLatitude = (self.worldFileData.yCoordinate + ((Double(self.worldFileData.imageHeight)) * self.worldFileData.yDimension) as CLLocationDegrees)
        let deltaX = fabs(self.worldFileData.xCoordinate - self.worldFileData.easternLongitude)
        let deltaY = fabs(self.worldFileData.yCoordinate - self.worldFileData.southernLatitude)
        worldFileData.boundingMapRect = MKMapRectMake(self.worldFileData.xCoordinate, //topLeft.x
                                 self.worldFileData.yCoordinate, //topLeft.y
                                 deltaX, //fabs(topLeft.x-topRight.x)
                                 deltaY) //fabs(topLeft.y - bottomLeft.y)
        worldFileData.midCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:((self.worldFileData.southernLatitude + (self.worldFileData.yCoordinate - self.worldFileData.southernLatitude)/2) as CLLocationDegrees), longitude: ((self.worldFileData.xCoordinate + (self.worldFileData.easternLongitude - self.worldFileData.xCoordinate)/2) as CLLocationDegrees))

    } else { print("Error parsing WorldData file.") }


    return worldFileData
}
```

Just prior to stepping over deltaX, the data is:

```
worldFileStringToParse  String  "0.00925265225497161\r\n0.000000\r\n0.000000\r\n-0.00925265225497161\r\n-80.2491661765359\r\n41.5148515181108\r\n"  
self    WeatherFun.WorldFileDataModel   0x000060000033b260
worldFileDataToParse    [String]    7 values    
worldFileData   WeatherFun.WorldFileDataModel.worldFileDataStruct   
xDimension  Double  0.0092526522549715995
rotationParam1  Double  0
rotationParam2  Double  0
yDimension  Double  -0.0092526522549715995
xCoordinate CLLocationDegrees   -80.249166176534999
yCoordinate CLLocationDegrees   41.51485151811
imageHeight Double  183.33333333333334
imageWidth  Double  200
easternLongitude    CLLocationDegrees   -78.398635725540686
southernLatitude    CLLocationDegrees   39.818531938031875
boundingMapRect MKMapRect   
midCoordinate   CLLocationCoordinate2D  
deltaX  CLLocationDegrees   
deltaY  CLLocationDegrees
```

The data after the step at deltaX is as follows:

```
worldFileStringToParse  String  "0.00925265225497161\r\n0.000000\r\n0.000000\r\n-0.00925265225497161\r\n-80.2491661765359\r\n41.5148515181108\r\n"  
self    WeatherFun.WorldFileDataModel   0x000060000033b260
worldFileDataToParse    [String]    7 values    
worldFileData   WeatherFun.WorldFileDataModel.worldFileDataStruct   
xDimension  Double  0.0092526522549715995
rotationParam1  Double  0
rotationParam2  Double  0
yDimension  Double  -0.0092526522549715995
xCoordinate CLLocationDegrees   -80.249166176534999
yCoordinate CLLocationDegrees   41.51485151811
imageHeight Double  183.33333333333334
imageWidth  Double  200
easternLongitude    CLLocationDegrees   -78.398635725540686
southernLatitude    CLLocationDegrees   39.818531938031875
boundingMapRect MKMapRect   
midCoordinate   CLLocationCoordinate2D  
deltaX  CLLocationDegrees   1.850530450994313
deltaY  CLLocationDegrees
```

When stepping over deltaY, the data is:

```
worldFileStringToParse  String  "0.00925265225497161\r\n0.000000\r\n0.000000\r\n-0.00925265225497161\r\n-80.2491661765359\r\n41.5148515181108\r\n"  
self    WeatherFun.WorldFileDataModel   0x000060000033b260
worldFileDataToParse    [String]    7 values    
worldFileData   WeatherFun.WorldFileDataModel.worldFileDataStruct   
xDimension  Double  0.0092526522549715995
rotationParam1  Double  0
rotationParam2  Double  0
yDimension  Double  -0.0092526522549715995
xCoordinate CLLocationDegrees   -80.249166176534999
yCoordinate CLLocationDegrees   41.51485151811
imageHeight Double  183.33333333333334
imageWidth  Double  200
easternLongitude    CLLocationDegrees   -78.398635725540686
southernLatitude    CLLocationDegrees   39.818531938031875
boundingMapRect MKMapRect   
midCoordinate   CLLocationCoordinate2D  
deltaX  CLLocationDegrees   
deltaY  CLLocationDegrees   1.696319580078125
```

When I step into the boundingMapRect calculation, this is my data:

```
worldFileStringToParse  String  "0.00925265225497161\r\n0.000000\r\n0.000000\r\n-0.00925265225497161\r\n-80.2491661765359\r\n41.5148515181108\r\n"  
self    WeatherFun.WorldFileDataModel   0x000060000033b260
worldFileDataToParse    [String]    7 values    
worldFileData   WeatherFun.WorldFileDataModel.worldFileDataStruct   
xDimension  Double  0.0092526522549715995
rotationParam1  Double  0
rotationParam2  Double  0
yDimension  Double  -0.0092526522549715995
xCoordinate CLLocationDegrees   -80.249166176534999
yCoordinate CLLocationDegrees   41.51485151811
imageHeight Double  183.33333333333334
imageWidth  Double  200
easternLongitude    CLLocationDegrees   -78.398635725540686
southernLatitude    CLLocationDegrees   39.818531938031875
boundingMapRect MKMapRect   
midCoordinate   CLLocationCoordinate2D  
deltaX  CLLocationDegrees   
deltaY  CLLocationDegrees
```

Does anyone have any clue of what is happening? The calculations appear to be correct in that the overlay mapRect should span that distance on the map. However, when entering the calculation for boundingMapRect, my deltaX seems to vanish. HELP!!!

Comment: Where do you get those data dumps from? That simply looks like the IDE deciding (for you) what data is "relevant" to show and data to omit.

Comment: @luk2302 From the debugger in Xcode. I just copied and pasted. Personally, I have never seen this happen before.

Comment: Are you accidentally debugging a Release build? Because `let` is optimized away, you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After following through further, the data ended up appearing again. I am not sure why this happened, and it is a bit disconcerting, but my advice into the future is to follow it all through.